# memory problem Ubuntu 14.04.4 server

Tags: server, java, ram

I've a problem with Ubuntu 14.04.4 Server. On this server it's running java (7 process that have set -Xms32M -Xmx512M) and corosync, every 4 months (more or less)  fills the memory (up to 100%) and starts to use the swap memory . The server running on a virtual machine on the Vmvare cluster and have 16 gb of ram. We have a crontab that run every hour the command

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

helps but not much. The only solution it's to restart the server. Any idea?

thanks.

Comment: Why so little allocated RAM? This is a minecraft server I'm guessing?

Comment: nope.. nothing minecraft